# String to list<double>

Tags: .net, string, parsing

I have a [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) composed of a series of real numbers separated by spaces or commas, like this:

> "645.974,255.478 645.973,255.468 645.97 0 233.54 21   "

I want to parse my string and fill a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with its numbers. I'm trying to find the quickest way to perform this task. So far I have tried the following methods, having a list of double and parsing the string hundred thousand times.

```
List<double> MyList = new List<double>(250);
```

- [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f7hht7k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): ~8.56[s]

  ```
  MyList.Clear();

  foreach (Match match in RgxDouble.Matches(Points))
          MyList.Add(double.Parse(match.Value));
  ```
- Unmanaged code with C++/CLI: ~7.5[s]

  ```
  static void UsingUnmanagedCode(wchar_t* points, List<double> ^MyList)
  {
      static char buffer[MAX_CHARS];
      wcstombs(buffer, points, MAX_CHARS);
      char *start = buffer, *ptr = buffer;

      for(; *ptr; ++ptr)
      {
          if(*ptr == ',')
              *ptr = ' ';
      }

      while(*(--ptr) == ' ')
          *ptr = '\0';

      char *pEnd;
      MyList->Add(strtod(start, &pEnd));

      while(*pEnd)
      {
          char *pStart = pEnd;
          MyList->Add(strtod(pStart, &pEnd));
      }
  }
  ```
- Unsafe code with C# and [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9sxk6fy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): ~2.4[s]

  ```
  MyList.Clear();

      fixed (char* fixPointsPtr = Points)
      {
          char* ptr = fixPointsPtr;

          while (*ptr != '\0')
          {
              if ((*ptr < '0' || *ptr > '9') && *ptr != '-' && *ptr != '.')
              {
                  MyList.Add(double.Parse(strBuild.ToString(0, strBuild.Length), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint));
                  strBuild.Length = 0;
              }

              else
                  strBuild.Append(*ptr);

              ++ptr;
          }
      }
  ```
- [String Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): ~2[s]

  ```
  MyList.Clear();

  foreach (string point in Points.Split(Separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
          MyList.Add(double.Parse(point, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint));
  ```

There is a better alternative?

Comment: There are few cases where the cost of *obtaining* the string isn't orders of magnitude more expensive than parsing it.  I/O is slow.

Comment: The version using `String.Split` is faster than any of the others, and simpler code. That's the one I'd go with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to assess the design of your program to see if you can split your string "on the fly" if speed is critical to you.

For example, how does your string come into your program? To make any algorithms ultra efficient, your best bet (as far as I know) is to try and condense your operations into a single loop... a single loop is automatically faster than multiple loops. An easy way to do this is to "listen" for your data as it comes in, char by char, byte by byte, adding a valid real number to your list as soon as you realize you have one.

Comment: I get string from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathitem.value.aspx). What do you mean with "on the fly"?

Comment: Whenever you're getting data from an outside source (i.e. XML, SQL, etc) you are "streaming" data in. A lot of times, the .NET framework handles streaming for you so all you get is the whole string and nothing else, but you can tell .NET to take a hike, allowing you to handle streaming yourself. Doing so affords you the opportunity to create your list as the data is streamed in, instead of having to do it after the string is already made (thus avoiding having a second loop.)

Comment: In the case of XPath, you should be able to create your own IXMLSerializable implementation ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)) where - instead of invoking XmlReader.ReadString() you create your own method for reading the string, and - as part of reading the string - you also create your list.  The effort is definitely not for amateurs, but if you're super concerned about performance, your only choice is always to go straight to the source and do it yourself.

Comment: I use [XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx) to parse the XML file, how could I across nodes and read the attributes instead of using that class?

Comment: You would need to abandon the XPath approach and create your own XML Serializer class, like I said. XPath is all about convenience, not efficiency. If possible, see if you can get your data via any other means but XML, as that's also not known for efficiency. Without knowing your situation, I would personally live with Stirng.Split's efficiency, or come up with a new data layer (if possible).

Comment: Of all the different ways to persist data, XML is one of the slowest/most inefficient. It has other uses to be sure, but if you're not happy with the performance you either need to stream your data (i.e. Files on hard disk, network source, web service, somewhere) or store it in an intermediate form like SQL where it's extremely fast to retrieve when needed.