# How to use c library in .net

Tags: c#, c

Hi I have created c library in visual studio 2017. I followed following steps to create C library. Under visual cpp I selected windows console application and I created simple hello world program. Please find the below screen shot.
[image]

Inside project CLibrary I got below folders after compiling

```
CLibrary.exe
CLibrary.ilk
Clibrary.pdb
```

[image]
Now I want to use this program in C#. I created one web api project. I want to access this CLibrary in my weapi project. Can someone tell me how can I use this c program in c#. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Using Solution Explorer in c# project right click application and select Add : Existing Item.  Then browse to c dll.  The c# compiler will automatically make a copy of dll and put into the c# bin folder and will update if dll in c project is newer than one in c#.  Then need to add a using statement at top of c# project with namespace (library name) of c project.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I have exe not dll. When I add exe does it automatically convert it to dll?

Comment: Did you know that you can search before ask ? https://www.codeproject.com/articles/9826/how-to-create-a-dll-library-in-c-and-then-use-it-w https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214630/use-c-library-in-net#10214812 https://www.google.com

Comment: You can't reuse functions in a C++ exe, change the C++ project type to library and build a dll

Comment: A exe is a dll with a main() method so you can run from windows,  No need to convert.  Just browse for the exe instead of the dll.

Comment: Thanks jdweng. I have added Clibrary.exe. I  have added using CLibrary; but It is giving error and not able to locate CLibrary. May I know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Do not start with console application.
You should create library in visual studio, after this you can use your cpp.dll as external.

c++ code

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int sum(int x,int y){return x+y;}//for windows
```

c# code for calling

```
[DllImport("yourdll.dll", EntryPoint = "sum")]
    internal unsafe static extern int Sum(int x,int y);
```

Comment: Thanks sea. which application type we need to select in visual studio to create c library?>

Comment: You can select dynamic-link library project type.

Comment: Thanks. I  have added screenshot above. Please let me know if I am selecting correct template.

Comment: Also above you have added c++ code and I am want c code. if I replace cpp to c will it work? thanks