# Compiling C code using `Ui Path` activites

Tags: c#, c, uipath, uipath-studio

Is there a way to compile a C code  in Visual Studio Code by UI Automation.I want to run the code and get the result by the using UiPath Studio.

Answer (score 1):

UiPath custom activities are using .NET classes and as far as I know there is no direct way to call C code from UiPath, there is Python, Java and PowerShell support in addition to built-in VB.NET and C# but to C.
That means that you have to resort to other methods:

1. **Invoke Method**

If you already have a C program your best bet is probably using [Invoke Method](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/invoke-com-method) activity to execute a method of a COM object. This way you could use any COM objects, not necessarily written in C

- **Custom Activity in C#**

If you just know how to write C code and want to use it with your robot create a new custom activity using [UiPath Activity Creator](https://docs.uipath.com/developer/docs/using-activity-creator) extension for Visual Studio, it's very straightforward and easy to use. You will need to write C# instead of C but it is rarely a big challege.

- **Custom activity in C# referencing C libraries**

If you go that way you could reference existing C code (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47708924/how-to-use-c-library-in-net) as an example of referencing C libraries in C#).

- **Compile C code into .NET**

Alternatively you could write a custom activity using something like [OrangeC](https://github.com/LADSoft/OrangeC) to compile your C code into .NET class but I think it's a little bit of too much hassle.